# The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have created a new DotNetCore 2.0 web project in VisualStudio 2017.
I have docker running in machine with Docker Server Host configured for Windows.

While running solution i'm getting below error,

> 'The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
>   string.'

Building myfirstdotnetcore Service 'myfirstdotnetcore' failed to
build:

> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
>   waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this issue and has resolved after taken below steps.

Run Visual Studio as Administrator

Your running Docker host should logged-in to your DockerHub account.

This is very important
The main reason for this issue is Visual Studio couldn't download nano server image from docker hub. So always make sure that you logged in to your dockerhub account from running host

Comment: Do you always run Visual Studio as administrator or is that just for initial configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to set docker registry Environment Variable. Path needs to be lowercase for some reason.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_REGISTRY", "d:\docker\registry\", "Machine")
```

Comment: how do you get the local registry path?

Comment: I had to remove existing env Variable with lower case. `$env:DOCKERVERSION=''; $env:DOCKERVERSION=$DOCKERVERSION;`

Answer (score 2):

I found these related issues on github:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/130 (this is tracking the fix)
- https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7234

TLDR; This error is misleading, and can mask several internal docker errors which Visual Studio currently swallows (these should be visible in your build output) - this is expected to be fixed in **Visual Studio 2017 15.8** but as of 15.8.2 this is still a problem and the bug is still open, so I assume its still on the way.

Until then, the general consensus seems to be that the following step combination should workaround most of the underlying issues. **NB! these might need to be repeated after machine restarts**.

- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Ensure you are logged in to Docker - e.g. run `docker login`
- Restart Docker for windows (right click in system tray and select restart)

I'm not certain if the order of the above might be important.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker Settings -> Network, I switched the DNS Server setting to "Fixed" as below and it worked for me! Hope that helps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything mentioned above but nothing worked. The issue for me was simply the fact that I did not have an environment variable named DOCKER_REGISTRY, as it clearly states in the error, so I created a system environment variable named DOCKER_REGISTRY and gave the path `C:` to it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117099/7802149) answer helped me. Remember to restart your system after creating the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the detailed error message?
I had a similar problem, turned out that virtualization wasn't enabled on my machine.

run 'systeminfo' in power shell, and make sure that hyper-v is enabled

Comment: @AvinashSingh try find the detailed error message
https://s33.postimg.cc/n6uaoxwen/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

I did almost like @David Silwal said.

I ran Visual Studio as Admin.

I was already logged-in on my docker hub account, but even like that, it wasn't working.

So I logged-out and logged-in again. Then, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project solution explorer and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Visual Studio as Administrator
2. Right click on Docker tray icon -> Restart