# VS2017 Build Fail - DOCKER_REGISTRY

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I'm getting started with Docker and familiar with .NET Core and Visual Studio 2017.  I've created a new Web Application (Razor Pages) named "WebApplicationCore21" with Docker Support enabled and receive a nice Dockerfile out the gate.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 62911
EXPOSE 44323

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplicationCore21/WebApplicationCore21.csproj WebApplicationCore21/
RUN dotnet restore WebApplicationCore21/WebApplicationCore21.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplicationCore21
RUN dotnet build WebApplicationCore21.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApplicationCore21.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplicationCore21.dll"]
```

While the project builds ok, it **errors on run** (F5), stating:

```
Description: The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Project: docker-compose
File: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets
Line: 363
```

*Steps verified*:

- Enabled Hyper-V on motherboard and in Windows 10 Pro
- Docker for Windows installed
- Can login both Docker Hub and client
- Switched Docker client to Windows containers from Linux

I've also noticed that although I can log into Docker client using my hub credentials, attempting to run `docker login` in PowerShell and using the same username/password produces the following:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Maybe this is helpful or perhaps unrelated; all I need is to run from VS2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my [solution](https://forums.docker.com/t/unauthorized-incorrect-username-or-password/35677/4) this morning based on the `unauthorized: incorrect username or password` error.

When I checked Docker for Windows in the system tray, I was logged in using my Docker Hub email address.  Docker for Windows finds this acceptable, which is misleading.  Doing so causes trouble for apps it interacts with like VS2017.  Using my Docker Hub username instead solved it.

Comment: Well that's just dumb.  I'm just starting to dabble in Docker, and stuff like this leaves a bad taste in my mouth... reminds me why I stick with Microsoft technologies. 
 Anyway, thanks for the solution!

Comment: wow stupidly at its best i cant believe that they did not fix this until now.
thanks you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Option-01 - You may need to replace     `image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}xxxxxxxxx`
with     `image:xxxxxx` in your `docker-compose.yml`

Option-02 Add env variable with name DOCKER_REGISTRY value set to any folder.If you get any error like name must be lowercase then change  the case of `DOCKER_REGISTRY` to lower case as `docker_registry`.

`docker-compose.yml` should be in your solution dir.

Comment: added as a system variable...which folder are we setting

Comment: to any folder .But a place where vs has write access.